# Verify given rank for each customer in the order from highest Purchase freq to low freq .?

Tags: sql

What can be sql query for table below?

i need to verify the table if it has given proper ranking to all customer to Customeritem Frequency from highest to lowest.

e.g.

for customer 1.

```
Cust   Rank    ItemFrequency
1        1           10
1        2           8
1        3           7
2       1           11
2       2            2
2       3            1
```

so, i need query to verify if it has rank to valid itemfrequecy to desc order

Updated 2 hours ago:
This can also work if

if data is  in correct order bring null result.

if its in wrong order bring only those out

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the rows were things are out of alignment, use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lag(itemfrequency) over (partition by cust order by rank) as prev_if
      from t
     ) t
where prev_if < itemfrequency;
```

Comment: CustomerId ItemCode RankByPurchaseFreq CustomerItemFrequency Department SubDepartment GroupId prev_if
5 33 3 7 NULL NULL 1 5
5 44 4 8 NULL NULL 1 7

result got only half of data,

Comment: If you see for customer 5 in image the rank is all wrong for all item frequency, you query gave only output for 2 records.

Comment: One more sub question to my question ,
how can i verify also if rank is in perfect order asc ??
if you see in image some of ranks dont start from 1 e.g (cust 3 where its ranks 1,1, 9) so i want also in proper 1,2,3 order , no duplicates or missing count.